# How to setup an ASP.NET Web Api app to run over HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've written a small web app, using Microsoft Web Api, but I'm new to the platform. How do I set it so it only works over https and if a user tries to access it over http he/she gets redirected?

Comment: This is something best controlled by the web server software, not the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this about what you're looking for?.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    //First, check the string for presence of HTTPS
    if (!String.Equals(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme, "https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
       //Tell the user they can't have your API - Error 400.
       actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
       {
       //Tell them so.
       Content = new StringContent("HTTPS Required")
    };
    return;
}
```

Edit: This is not original but I've used it before effectively.  Hope it helps.